# Synonym to "by default" in this context

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, american-english

Consider the following sentence:

> Good design can make a **by default** cheaper car and one that can also be further configured, potentially leading to cost reductions of several orders of magnitude.

What would be a good substitute to "by default" in this sentence, that would make it flow better? Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: _implicitly_ may work.

Comment: No, that doesn't sound right in this context. I really need something that means "by default" - such as "defaultly", if that words existed.

Comment: _inherently_ should do it, then!

Comment: Just move default: *Good design can make a cheaper car by default and...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Inherently*** may work here.

> Good design can make an ***inherently*** cheaper car and one that can
>   also be further configured, potentially leading to cost reductions of
>   several orders of magnitude.

ODO:

> **[inherently](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inherently)**
>
> *ADVERB*
>
> In a permanent, essential, or characteristic way:
>   ‘the work is
>   inherently dangerous’
>   ‘his theories are inherently flawed’
>   ‘criticism
>   is inherently threatening’